# Setting up Django to connect to local SQLExpress in windows

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have successfully installed and setup Django in windows. I have also created my first project using django default database setting. 
However, I would like to change the DATABASE settings to connect to my local SQLExpress.

Here is my DATABASE settings in settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'NAME': 'mytestdb',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'test_user',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        }
}
```

After I saved the file, I ran into a problem where it says "Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]".

I am able to connect to my local SQLExpress server using SQL Server Management studio. I know that the server is running. I've tried to google it and tried different setups, and I couldn't get it running.

This is the error that I've got when I ran syncdb command:

> python manage.py syncdb
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft SQL Server Native Clien
>   t 10.0', u'Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ', None, 0, -2147467259), None), u'Error
>    opening connection: DATA SOURCE=localhost;Initial Catalog=mytestdb;UID=test_user;PWD=******;PROVIDER=sqlncli10;DataTy
>   peCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True')

Here is my installed packages:
C:\windows\system32>pip freeze

Django==1.7.6

django-auth-ldap==1.2.5

django-mssql==1.6.2

pyodbc==3.0.7

python-ldap==2.4.19

pywin32==219

virtualenv==12.0.7

I am using Django development server.

Does the error "Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]" is more to the user authentication error or couldn't find the SQL server?

Comment: I managed to get it working now. Sigh. I've changed the HOST value to '127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS' and somehow it works!

Answer (score 4):

In this case, your `HOST` string needs to contain both computer name or address and an Instance ID Las set during the installation procedure (`SQLEXPRESS` by default).

Use:
`'HOST': 'COMPUTER-NAME\\SQLEXPRESS'`
or
`'HOST': '127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS'`

[image: Installation screen]